# ionic Loading Controller Cancel and Return

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

This seems like a simple thing but I wasn't able to implement it and didn't find information on it.

I have an ionic Loading Controller that initiates when processing some data. This might take time so the user might decide to cancel. So I would like to simply add a cancel button in the loading element which dismisses the loading controller and returns to the previous page.

```
  this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
    content: 'Loading ... (cancel button here?)'
  });
  this.loading.present();
```

Comment: Did you try experiment with loading options like “content”. Docs say it is there for custom html?

Comment: I tried custom html. I just enabled backdrop for now, even though that's not want I'm looking for.

Comment: can you share your implementation, I think what you want is doable

Answer (score 0):

As far s I know it is not supported. I did it with a modal, it works nearly the same and has the same syntax, but you don't have the transparent background.
See: https://www.techiediaries.com/ionic-modals/ for implementation.